# Importregex Cryptotracker formula used to work, what happened?

Tags: google-sheets

I've been using this formula to track the prices of cryptocurrencies...

=IMPORTREGEX(F13,"<div(?=[^>]*class=””priceValue___11gHJ .*””)[^>]*>$(.+?)</div>”)")

The cell referenced here is for this site: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/pax-gold/?update=1626649033501

it had been working, but now it shows an error: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /<div(?=[^>]*class=””priceValue___11gHJ .*””)[^>]*>$(.+?)</div>”)/: Unmatched ')' (line 109).

I don't know how to read this error, so I'm not sure how to fix it. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTXML(
 "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/pax-gold/?update=1626649033501",
 "//*"), "select Col1 where Col1 contains '@context'", 0), "price..(\d+.\d+|\d+)")*1
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTXML(F12,
 "//*"), "select Col1 where Col1 contains '@context'", 0), 
 "price..(\d+.\d+.\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)")*1, 
 REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTXML(F12,
 "//*"), 
 "select Col1 where Col1 contains 'relatedExchangePairsList' and Col1 starts with ' 1'"),
 "\$ (\d+.\d+.\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+) ")*1))
```

[image]

Comment: that works! and I added the cell reference in, and it still seems to work, though sometimes it adds the update=162...... to the end of the price for some reason...

Comment: @mschumpert can you share a copy of your sheet where it results in adding the update?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14d-Ts6cCJBXE01pkaIFFoimPc1b8IyAK_akoizEzXqA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have your link in h13 that works, but when I copy it to h12 where i want it, it changes

Comment: it's still messing up, but this is due to my error...your formula works in h13, but when I copy it to g13 (where I want it), it messes up

Comment: @mschumpert make sure that after you copy it you still have F13 cell reference in your formula and not E13

Comment: that worked! but i'm not sure how...thanks so much!